# Acessing Navigate Bar in Android With Appium

Tags: java, android, junit, appium

I need to automate a test that consists of simulating the touches on the navigate bar, it cannot be just the command.

I tried to simulate the touch with this:

```java
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
action.tap(PointOption.point(530, 2400)).perform();
```

But appears the error that the Coordinate [x=530.0, y=2400.0] is outside of element rectangle.

And it needs to be simulating the touch on the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A friend of mine have achieved the result you are looking for by reading the id for the  page you want to tap on, in this case the id it's home

```
  public AppiumWebElement HomeTab => AppiumDriver.FindElementById("com.package.appname/home");
```

and then using the following  `HomeTab.Click();`